# Isn't "But my pay was not even quite enough for one person much less several." missing a comma?

Tags: grammar, commas

> But my pay was not even quite enough for one person much less several.

Isn't a comma missing here? Should it not be:

> But my pay was not even quite enough for one person, much less several.

?

I've often seen native English/American speakers/writers, and often quite intelligent ones, make this "mistake", and thus I'm beginning to think that it is not a mistake at all. But it seems very wrong to me. It doesn't look right to omit a comma, and it suggests to me that the author is prone to making "comma splices" in other contexts, sort of "shifting the meaning" of the comma.

Comment: The position of ***even*** in your example text is non-idiomatic. I realise that you can make a case for saying there are two different *nuances* of meaning, depending on where you place it, but in practice the only idiomatic phrasing there is ***my pay was not quite enough for even one person***. And that's *regardless* of whether it's followed by the entirely optional "intensifier" ***much less several*** (which optional element could be separated from earlier text by a comma *or* a dash - or even a full stop, although that would be a fairly unusual stylistic choice).

Comment: The comma is not mandatory; 'much less several' is parenthetical (ie can be omitted without leaving a matrix sentence that is ungrammatical or significantly different in meaning) (although it obviously contains important additional information). Nowadays, it is in general acceptable to use commas (one comma for initial of terminal parentheticals), dashes, or a pair of brackets – _or zero punctuation_ – to offset parentheticals. That being said, in this case I'd consider the comma by far the best choice (though a dash could be used to add drama). But 'mistake' might be too severe a judgement.